# High constant CPU on Aurora/RDS

Tags: amazon-rds, aws, cpu, aws-aurora

I've noticed recently that our resting CPU on our Aurora RDS cluster appears to be about 80%. I'm unsure when this started, as we don't have alarms/metrics in place (something I plan to rectify now).

It's a 2 node cluster db.t2.medium. Normally with a MySQL/MariaDB instance I'd troubleshoot on the actual machine, however the trade off of cloud services is that I can't really do this.

*CPU:*
[image: CPU usage]

*Query count per second:*
[image: Query count per second]

We have a script that normalises some data every 10 minutes, and the spikes I see there reflect the 10-15% jump, which I'd expect. However we appear to be constantly resting around the 70-80% mark. The update, insert and delete throughput per second never exceeds 4/s, so I can't imagine other operations are affecting it.

Why would this be, and how can this be troubleshot?

Comment: You shouldn't be performing DDL in any sort of regular way on a live system - if that's what you're doing?

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
RAM size, # cores of your MySQL Host server 
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.